# vector subspace and its addition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S and T be two vector subspaces of vector space V; when does S+T equal S union T?

I intuitively got when S is a subset of T or T is a subset of S.

Comment: You are correct if by $S+T$ you mean the direct sum ? Note since $S, T$ are subspaces the "subset" relationship is also in fact  a subspace relationship.

Answer (score 0):

A general result to begin with is that if $S, T$ are subspaces then $S \cup T$ is a subspace if and only if one is a subspace of the other.
Proof:
Suppose that $S \cup T$ is a subspace and $S$ is not a subspace of $T$.
Then there is $s_0 \in S $ and $s_0 \not\in T$.
For all $t \in T$,  $s_0 + t \in S \cup T$ (since this latter is a subspace and $s_0, t \in S \cup T \implies s_0 + t \in S \cup T$)
Since $s_0 \not \in T$ then $s_0 + t \not \in T$ (since $T$ is a subspace and $-t \in T$ would then imply $s_0 \in T$)
So $s_0 + t \in S \cup T \implies s_0 + t \in S $
And  $s_0 \in S \implies -s_0 \in S \implies t \in S$
Therefore if  $S$ is not a subspace of $T$ then  $T$ is a subspace of $S$.

The converse is obvious as if one is a subspace of the other their union is equal to one of them and is therefore a subspace.

Then to prove the specific result, you should know that the direct sum is a subspace so $S \oplus T = S \cup T \implies  S \cup T $ is a subspace $\implies$ the subspace relationship between $S, T$ by the above.
Conversely the subspace relationship between $S, T \implies S\cup T = T$ (say) and $\implies  S \oplus T = T \implies  S\cup T =  S \oplus T$